# Performing non-rolling Kubernetes updates

Tags: kubernetes, updates, kops

I am new to Kubernetes and kops. I am experimenting and modifying my test cluster a lot.

My problem is that updating the cluster takes forever. For now I am doing:

```
kops edit cluster test-cluster.k8s.local
# changing some stuff then:
kops update cluster test-cluster.k8s.local --yes
```

This triggers [a rolling update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/update/update-intro/), which takes too long.

I end up destroying and rebuilding the cluster every time as it is faster.

I am wondering if there's a "non-rolling" way to update the cluster, sacrificing availability for speed?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a deployment object for deploying your pods, you can try `Recreate` strategy in your deployment yaml.

References

- https://codefresh.io/kubernetes-tutorial/continuous-deployment-strategies-kubernetes-2/
- https://www.slideshare.net/EtienneTremel/kubernetes-deployment-strategies-cncf-webinar